# HTML form submit fail with "><" in text box

Tags: html, forms, special-characters

When there is "><"  [lesser than] and [greater than] together, my form fails to submit or the php file is not able to pick it up. can someone explain to me what is the exact problem? and how can I submit this text

```
<form action="/aa.php" method="post" >
  <input type="text" name="a1" value="><">
  <input type="submit">
</form>
```

the above code returns "page not found once submitted".
If I emptied or give something else to the textbox, it loads the second page.

my second page (the handler)

```
<?php
  print_r($_POST);
?>
```

Comment: What happens if you do `value="&gt;&lt;"`

Comment: @mplungjan - this is not a good solution at all. The solution must be on the PHP-side.

Comment: Still the same result

Comment: I can't see any reason why that would result in a 404 error.

Comment: I try your code in local and all work. are you sure aa.php is correct path?

Comment: Life is too short for this Q to be A

Comment: Just tested it. I can't reproduce the problem.

Comment: What is your HTML file document *encoding*? (meta tag)

Comment: @kumaDK — I did. That's what "Just tested it. I can't reproduce the problem." means.

Comment: https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.htmlspecialchars.php
fiddle around with this

Comment: @Zircoz — Why? The only special character which has any meaning in that context is `"`, which they aren't using.

Comment: You are describing 2 completely different problems here. ***decide*** if you want help regarding `404` or that the value `><`  is the cause of the problem.

Comment: @vsync — The OP says that the 404 is caused by the `><`

Comment: Wild speculation: You have an over-eager XSS filter which is throwing a 404 instead of an appropriate error message.

Comment: So what can be done to get rid of this???

Comment: is it just `><` ? does only `<` or `>` cause the same problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to solve the problem by turning off mod security. It was mod security blocking the requests when some special character sequences were there.